# Combinatorics of merging sequences from multinomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, multinomial-coefficients

If you have $m$ sequences $a_{11},\dots,a_{1n_1}$ through $a_{m1},\dots,a_{mn_m}$ each sorted in ascending order (assume there are no duplicates) then there is an unique way to merge them.

1. How many possible merging combinations arise this way (each of the sequences could have arbitrary relative ordering with respect to others and so the number of permutations is not the entire permutation group cardinality)?
2. What if there are duplicates?

For 1. essentially I want to know is it a similar to a multinomial number?

Comment: I think you're talking about what are often called "shuffles"

Comment: @SamHopkins Perhaps. Is there a link?

Comment: See e.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/shuffle or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riffle_shuffle_permutation

Comment: @SamHopkins Thank you for the link. So is my guess correct that these are related to multinomials? I do not see multinomials in either link. The first seems pretty abstract as well.

Comment: They are related to multinomials. In the links they only discuss the case of shuffling two ordered lists, which give binomially many shuffles. Multinomials arise when you have more than two ordered lists. This can be seen from the fact that shuffles of x,y,z can be obtained by first shuffling x and y, and then shuffling the result with z (and the fact that multinomials can all be written as products of binomials).

Comment: Anyways it is obvious that the number of shuffles is a multinomial because you just choose for each ordered list the positions that that list occupies. (Things are more complicated if the ordered lists have letters in common, of course.)

Comment: @SamHopkins Regarding your iterated shuffling.. there is more than one way to do shuffle four sequences (you can merge 1,2 and 3.4 and then merge 12 and 34 or 1,4 and 2.3 and then 14 and 23 and so on). It is not clear to me what the symmetries would be and what is the count?

Comment: The count is still a multinomial, and I think I've explained multiple ways to see that. If I want to think of all shuffles of x,y,z, and w, first I shuffle x and y in all possible ways, then shuffle all those results with z, and then shuffle all those results with w.

Comment: @SamHopkins So the number is exactly $$\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^m n_i)!}{\sum_{i=1}^m n_i!}$$ correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: For some work in this area see https://dmtcs.episciences.org/2718/pdf. See also http://www.birs.ca/workshops/2011/11w5025/files/smith-barnes-poster.pdf for a summary of results.